# See Build Artifacts in Azure DevOps with YAML Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I seem to be missing something. When creating a build pipeline with the classic editor I can see an artifacts tab on the top right:

[image]

There I can browse what the compiler created, helping to find out the folder structure for the release pipeline.

Now when I create a build pipeline with the YAML template (also NET Framework) there is no such thing as Artifacts:

[image]

According to the logs, some files have been written. Is there some kind of browser for files, or do I have to guess which of [these variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#system-variables) match to which folder in the logfiles?

This is how my summary page looks like:
[image]

This is the YAML:

```
# .NET Desktop
# Build and run tests for .NET Desktop or Windows classic desktop solutions.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/windows/dot-net

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

The YAML i use is mostly the standard YAML produced when building from a Github Repository. Does this affect if i can see Artifacts? Should i somehow copy the Github content to Azure first and then build it?

Comment: Can you share your YAML?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: i found the problem:
The default YAML file for GitHub Builds does NOT include a "publish" Step. After adding this to the end of the Build YAML

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

it in fact creates the "Artifacts" Tab:
[image]

Thanks for the help anyone

Comment: Awesome to know! You can accept it as answer after 2 days:-)  For the difference between our summary page, it is because I enable the preview feature of **Multi-stage builds**. You could have a try with this new feature.

Answer (score 3):

This seems be the different UI of `classic` and `YAML`.

To see the artifacts structure, you can go **summary** page(*https://dev.azure.com/xxxx/xxxx/_build/results?buildId=xxx&view=results*) of one build. Then focus one the right part and you will see like below:

[image]

Click on it, then you will see its folder structure(*https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_build/results?buildId=xxx&view=artifacts&type=publishedArtifacts*):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that is not how my summary page looks like. I added more information and a screenshot to the Question. Could you please review it?

Comment: @JensCaasenj, not sure what's wrong, error occured when I want to open your screenshots https://imgur.com/a/v549YhE. Would you mind share with this Imgur again?